# Transforming positions and adding a constant z axis valueC#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started working on another project where one of the game mechanics is the ability to relocate a drone to the position of your mouse cursor.

Here is my code below where I have several problems(will specify)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class lightDrone : MonoBehaviour
{
Vector3 newPosition;

void Start()
{
    newPosition = transform.position + (0,0,10); //***Problem A***
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            newPosition = hit.point;
            transform.position = newPosition; // ***Problem B***
        }
    }
}
}
```

Problem A - I am trying to have the new position = wherever the cursorhas clicked + 10 on the y axis so the "Drone" is seemed to be flying and not in the ground. This isn't achieving anything and is just giving me compiling errors.

I want the exact position to be (cursor.x, (public int (y)), cursor.z) but I have a very vague idea to do it.

Problem B -

Currently when I click my mouse, the object moves to the cursor but it seems to be just teleporting instantly. I want it to move at a certain speed and I think I need a public float to do so and change transform.position to translate.position but this again doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for answering my questions, I am trying to learn these new mechanics and how to code them. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Problem A

If you want your new position to be where ever the cursor clicked + 10 on the y axis it makes no sense to put *any* of your code in `Start()`. That's for initialization only. It runs just once at the beginning of the scene. Just add the 10 to your newPosition in the `Update()` method.

### Problem B

Setting `transform.position` to a certain value will make your transform *instantly* move to that position. If you want to do it over time you need to move your transform a few increments at a time. Since this introduces that "over time" element, you need to use a method that takes place over time, so you need coroutines, asyncs or you can use just the update method if you're a tiny bit crafty.

**Also you need the ray to intersect and hit *something*. Like a flat plane, the ground, terrain, anything with a collider. If it doesn't hit anywhere then you won't have a new place to move to.**

### Code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LightDrone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 60.0f;

    // Our destination needs to be remembered outside a single iteration of
    // Update. So we put it outside of the method in order to remember it
    // across multiple frames.
    private Vector3 currentDestination;

    // We need to check if we're at the destination yet so we know when to stop.
    private bool notAtDestinationYet;

    // When we're closer to the destination than this tolerance, we decide that
    // we have arrived there.
    private float tolerance = 0.1f;

    private void  Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                var newPosition = hit.point;
                // You can add whatever height you want here. I added
                // just 2 instead of 10.
                currentDestination = newPosition + new Vector3(0, 2.0f, 0);
                notAtDestinationYet = true;
            }
        }

        if (notAtDestinationYet)
        {
            // Use a bit of vector math to get the direction from our current
            // position to the destination. The direction is a normalized Vector
            // that we can just multiply with our speed to go in that direction
            // at that specific speed!

            var heading = currentDestination - transform.position;
            var distance = heading.magnitude;
            var direction = heading / distance;

            // Check if we've arrived at our destination.
            if (distance < tolerance)
            {
                notAtDestinationYet = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // If the remaining distance between us and the destination is
                // smaller than our speed, then we'll go further than necessary!
                // This is called overshoot. So we need to make our speed
                // smaller than the remaining distance.

                // We also multiply by deltaTime to account for the variable
                // amount of time that has passed since the last Update() call.
                // Without multiplying with the amount of time that has passed
                // our object's speed will increase or decrease when the
                // framerate changes! We really don't want that.

                float currentSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(speed * Time.deltaTime,
                    Mathf.Epsilon, distance);
                transform.position += direction * currentSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, haven't tested it yet but You showed me how raycasts work. I would of never thought of all these things to consider for such a simple concept on paper. You made my day :)

Comment: Heh, I didn't expect to get such a positive response. I'm glad it helped!